# Returning more verbose error messages from HttpClient on a revoked certificate?

Tags: c#, ssl, tls1.2

I'm writing code against a web server that does client certificate authentication. I make a WebRequestHandler with my certificate chain, pass that into a HttpClient object and then call PostAsync on the HttpClient. This works fine with a valid certificate on the chain of trust that is not revoked. The HttpResponseMessage task faults when the certificate is revoked (as is expected) and Exception member contains this aggregate exception:

> An error occurred while sending the request.
>
> The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

My problem is that I need a more verbose error. If I do the same thing (submit the same revoked client certificate) from Chrome I get this error:

ERR_BAD_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT

And from Internet Explorer:

ERROR_INTERNET_SEC_CERT_REVOKED

How can I get such an error? I need to tell the user not only that it didn't work but WHY. The fact that browsers get a more precise error seems to indicate that more information is coming back that just the fault exception. It doesn't seem to be because of intentional obfuscation.

Code sample:

```
WebRequestHandler handler = new WebRequestHandler();

if (certCol != null)
{
    foreach (X509Certificate2 cert in certCol)
    {
        handler.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
    }
}
else
{
    sLastErr = "Could not find client certificate to communicate. Certificate collection is NULL.";
    LogHelper.LogGenericError(
        _logger,
        sLastErr
        );
    return false;
}

_HttpClient = new HttpClient(handler);

_HttpClient.PostAsync(uriCM, reqContent).ContinueWith(requestTask => 
{
    HttpResponseMessage httpRespContent = null;
    bool bSuccess = false;
    if (requestTask.IsCompleted)
    {
        if (requestTask.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
        {
            httpRespContent = requestTask.Result;
            bSuccess = true;
        }
        else if(requestTask.Status == TaskStatus.Faulted)
        {
            if (requestTask.Exception != null)
            {
                LogHelper.LogErrorWithAggregateException(_logger, "PostAsync call faulted.", requestTask.Exception);
                //exception messages in aggregate exception:
                //An error occurred while sending the request.
                //The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
            }
            else
                LogHelper.LogError(_logger, "PostAsync call faulted.");
        }
        else
        {
            LogHelper.LogError(_logger, "PostAsync call failed.");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        LogHelper.LogError(_logger, "PostAsync call never completed. Communication Failure.");
    }

    if (bSuccess)
    {
        //it worked, do stuff...        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Browsers, like any other TLS client, do the tests locally, they do not get the fault from outside. Then they get to display whatever details they want about the problem encountered, based on their tests. So recovering what happened exactly only depends on the TLS handling library you use, and the checks it does for you.

Comment: hmm. the browser has no knowledge of the revocation list locally though. so how would it tell the difference between a revoked certificate and any other condition?

Comment: The browser downloads the CRL from the URL present in the certificate, and hence tests locally if the certificate is in the specific CRL. And there are other revoked cases: OCSP, outside of CA CRL lists, Certificate Transparency Logs, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SslStream throws a Win32 exception that reports that the certificate is revoked if it is revoked. Like the browsers. Seems to be hitting Schannel or some un-managed code at a lower level and piping it up. If HttpClient returns a TLS error, I run my code to try to make a SslStream+TcpClient connection and report the exception. I guess HttpClient just buries the error details and SslStream exposes it in an inner exception. Solves my problem.

Sample code:

```
    public bool VerifyThatCanAuthenticateAsClient()
    {
        bool bSuccess = false;
        TcpClient tcpClient = null;
        SslStream sslStream = null;

        try
        {
            tcpClient = new TcpClient(
                _sHostname,
                _iPort
            );

            bSuccess = true;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            //log exception
        }

        if(bSuccess)
        {
            bSuccess = false;

            try
            {
                sslStream = new SslStream(
                    tcpClient.GetStream(),
                    false,
                    new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate),
                    new LocalCertificateSelectionCallback(SelectLocalCertificate),
                    EncryptionPolicy.RequireEncryption
                    );

                bSuccess = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //log exception
            }
        }

        if (bSuccess)
        {
            bSuccess = false;

            try
            {
                sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(
                    _sHostname,
                    null,
                    System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls12,
                    false
                    );

                bSuccess = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //log ex.message exception

                if(ex.InnerException != null)
                {
                    //log ex.innerexception.message
                    //this is what gives me the low level error that means its revoked if it is, or other specific tls error
                }
            }
        }

        if(sslStream != null)
        {
            sslStream.Dispose();
        }

        if(tcpClient != null)
        {
            tcpClient.Dispose();
        }

        return bSuccess;
    }
```