# Strange TLS client cert handshake issue with C# ASP.Net Core app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a strange problem. The app in question is:

- ASP.Net Core 2.2 running on .Net Framework 4.7.2
- Running under IIS 8.5 unmanaged

This app has to contact a REST service in the background. This REST service requires a client cert. I use System.Net.Http.HttpClient to connect to the REST service using the client cert over TLS 1.2.

This works. However, after a day or so, it just stops working and returns

```
The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel
```

Even restarting the IIS app doesn't fix this. It usually just starts working again and I can't work out the circumstances which lead to this. Rebooting the server doesn't even necessarily fix it. The remote REST app has no issues with the (many) other client libs talking to it. I have exactly the same issue in DEV/TRAIN and PROD instances of the same app. Just to be clear, it *does* work, it just suddenly stops working after some time so I know the client cert works and TLS 1.2 works. I also use TLS 1.2 and the exact same client cert to the same REST endpoint in several other apps in completely different languages (PowerShell, perl) without any problems at all.

I cannot work out what is happening. I have tried reading the client cert from the filesystem before every REST call and also reading it once in the Startup class and injecting it. Both approaches have the same issue.

Now, one thing I am suspicious of is that this client REST call is not running async as it's in a static method but I can't see how that would have this result. If I look at the remote server logs for the REST endpoint, I see an error saying that no client certificate was supplied. I have put in debugging to write the client cert thumbprint in my local app logs just before the REST call to make sure that the client cert is really there for the call and it is - the logs always contain the correct client cert thumbprint in the logs just before the failed REST call.

**Update**: I modified the REST call so that it is async and it makes no difference. I am now reusing one instance of `HttpClient` with the client cert loaded and still this error starts to happen after a while.

Any ideas much appreciated.

Comment: If the handshake is working and then it stops working after certain period. I would assume probably timestamps are not in sync. Please check if 1) Are the app server and api server are in sync with respect to the timestamp? 2) Are you sending any authorization header with a signature containing expired timestamp?

Comment: HttpClient tends to hide low level errors for some reason. Try sslstream for a more verbose error. I had a similar problem getting definitive errors on revoked certs. You can try using HttpClient and if that fails, call sslstream (probably calling schannel under the covers) to see what it throws (see answer): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51829235/returning-more-verbose-error-messages-from-httpclient-on-a-revoked-certificate

Comment: @Rasik Jain - I am not sending any specific custom headers, however, the auth for this REST API is done by Kerberos so it could be something to do with those header - we all know how sensitive Kerberos is to time sync ....